# Which syntax is preferred to create a Hash in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am writing some code in Ruby on Rails to **Create an object**.

I am using **Ruby 2.0** and **Rails 4.0.3** in my Application.

I have a Model called:

```
class GroupUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :group
```

This is basically a ManyToMany mapping between Users and Groups.
So, today I was creating an object for this Model.

But I found out I could follow **two syntax** for this, as follows

```
GroupUsers.create( :user => user, :group => group )
```

Or

```
GroupUsers.create( user: user, group: group )
```

Basically since this is **related to creating a Hash** so it must be a question of **the best practice in Ruby**.

**Which syntax should be preferred ?**

Comment: I suggest adopting a style guide appropriate to the Ruby version of your project and adhering to that.  ruby-style-guide enforces Ruby 1.9 style hash syntax for Ruby 1.9+ projects, for example.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. I prefer the newer syntax because I feel that it is more readable. As others have pointed out, however, the newer syntax is only compatible with Ruby 1.9.2+.

You should be aware, however, that the new syntax does not entirely replace the hash rocket syntax. This is because you can only use the newer syntax with symbols.

```
{ "text": :hello } #=> syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
```

If you want to use strings and methods, you will still need to use the has rocket:

```
{ method_name => :hello }
{ "a_string" => :hello }
```

Personally, from my experience of reading and watching educational materials, the newer syntax is preferred where possible. It's also less keystrokes: `:` instead of `=>` is easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the Ruby version you're using. If you're using Ruby 1.9.2+ then the second syntax is cleaner in terms of readability.

If you're using Ruby 1.8 then you can't use the second syntax anyway and you have not choice.

Comment: Please expand this answer a bit, to explain *why* a syntax is cleaner with such or such version of Ruby.

Comment: @Mat'sMug edited.

Comment: I Added "cleaner in terms of readability"

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can also create an ActiveRecord object with a [block passed](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/07/active-record-loves-blocks/):

```
GroupUsers.create do |gu|
  gu.user = user
  gu.group = group
end
```

though I don't think it's suitable with just a few attributes being set. However, I'd suggest renaming the robot-like `GroupUsers` into `Membership`, for example.